# What is the lifetime of eccentric-weight haptic actuator?

Tags: motor, cellphone

Typically 40ms duration, few thousands times per day. What would be its life expectancy?

Comment: Having a damaged phone vibrator is probably the same as having the phone vibrator switched off. At the end of the day you'll get "so-many" cycles from the motor and your question appears to boil-down to "is it better to use the cycles up now and gain the benefit from them now or conserve them and gain no benefit except maybe I can sell the phone as a working item when I get a new one" - this isn't an electrical engineering question so I also vote to close.

Comment: If you re-worded this as an engineering question about lifetime of eccentric-weight haptic actuators with the cell phone as an example, it would probably be well-received.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am not sure of the wording as I am not an electrician. Please feel free to edit my attempt to reword the question :)

Comment: I would expect a manufacturer's data sheet to have data about expected lifetime. Things like switches and relays have ratings for number of actuations, connectors are rated for number of insertions.

Comment: 40 ms isn't enough time for a motor to make even one full revolution from a dead stop. The puropse is simply to create a little jerk that you can feel as feedback for your typing. I would think that the wear on the motor from this type of usage would be much less than when it runs full-speed for a second or two at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motors have a typical life of a [few hundred hours](https://catalog.precisionmicrodrives.com/order-parts/datasheet/304-008-4mm-vibration-motor-9-3mm-type) maybe more if they are brushless, but the bearings also are under stress with the eccentric mass.

If they run for 50ms each press, that's something like 20,000,000 key presses, which doesn't sound too terrible.

It's possible the short blips are a bit more stressful, but I doubt this is huge issue given the short life of most such portable electronics.

Comment: Ah thank you.  I use the 40ms duration.  But I type really fast so the off period between each press is minimal. This I think won't be so good for the motor.